# SQL - Selecting records by the newest date for each record

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with some columns, amongst which there are two - `number`, `joining_date`.
What I want to select is the newest joining date and matching number. I created the following script:

```
SELECT ac.number, ac.joining_date
FROM accounts ac
         INNER JOIN (
    SELECT number, MAX(joining_date) as maxDate FROM accounts GROUP BY number
) iac ON ac.number = iac.number AND ac.joining_date = iac.maxDate;
```

It seems fine, however, I have noticed that when the `joining_date` is equal i.e. `2020-04-02 10:17:00.000000` for more than one record, the `number` appears twice in the result, even if the `MAX` should return only one row.

**Question**: how to retrieve only one `number` by the newest `joining_date`? Is `DISTINCT` guarantees that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the DISTINCT ON clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(number) number, joining_date
FROM accounts
ORDER BY number, joining_date DESC
```

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. But lets assume that I have third column `status`. Since distinct applies by the first number occurency, the latest status may be invalid.

Comment: The number of columns returned by the query is not relevant. With DISTINCT ON the result is exactly 1 row for each number and that row is the 1st row as it is fetched by the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I overlooked the postgres tag, rendering my answer not very useful.

Original answer:

There are several options, and I usually use CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT ac.number, ac.joining_date
FROM accounts ac
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 a.number, a.joining_date 
             FROM accounts a 
             WHERE a.number = ac.number AND a.joining_date = ac.joining_date
             ORDERBY a.joining_date DESC) iac
```

Another option is to use `Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.number ORDER BY a.joining_date DESC) as rownum` in the subquery, while also adding `WHERE rownum=1` to ensure only one match.

Comment: Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't support CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Postgres follows the SQL standard, you would need to use `cross join lateral` there (instead of the non-standard `cross apply`)

Comment: @Ayam . . . Postgres does support lateral joins (what `cross apply` does).  It uses a different syntax.